# pagination in codeigniter and passing values to a controller function but pagination not working

Tags: codeigniter

controller file:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Departments extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->model('login_model','',TRUE);
        $this->load->model('pariskarmodel','',TRUE);


    }

    public function index($id)
    {


            $this->load->library("pagination");
            $config = array();
            $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "departments/index";
            $config["total_rows"] = $this->pariskarmodel->mng_departments_count_check($id);
            $config["per_page"] = 3;
            $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
            $data['news_data']=$this->pariskarmodel->mng_departments_check($config["per_page"],$page,$id);
            $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $this->load->view('departments',$data);
    }

}

 ?>
```

view Page:

```
<u>
 <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>departments">Departments</a></li>
<li ><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>departments/index/1">Film</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>departments/index/2">TV</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>departments/index/3">Game</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>departments/index/4">Commercials</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>departments/index/5">Events & Awards</a></li>
             .
             .
             .
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>departments/index/15">Events & Awards</a></li>
</ul>
```

Model page:

```
function mng_departments_check($limit,$start,$id)
        {

        echo $sql="select * from tbl_departments where category='$id'  order by id DESC  limit $start,$limit";

            $query=$this->db->query($sql);
            return $query->result();
        }
        function mng_departments_count_check($id)
        {
            $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_departments where category='$id' order by id DESC";
            $query=$this->db->query($sql);
            return $query->num_rows();
        }
```

result is:when am i click link one(file) sql query is :

```
select * from tbl_departments where category='1' order by id DESC limit 1,3
```

click link two(file) sql query is :

```
select * from tbl_departments where category='2' order by id DESC limit 2,3
```

if am i click link 15 sql query is :

```
select * from tbl_departments where category='15' order by id DESC limit 15,3
```

i cannot why category(category='15') is change in sql and pagination also not work.i put $this->uri->segment(4) also but not work .

Comment: is category id passing correctly?  problem in `limit 15,3`? Right?

Comment: yes kumar ,my problem is passing id and uri_segment.i solve my answer by adding id in $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "departments/index/".$id; and $config["uri_segment"] = 4;

Comment: +1 Ok. but late reply :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

`$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "departments/index/".$id;`

if it helps 
please mark it as answer..

Comment: Could you please explain briefly

Comment: your index function require `$id` every time u make a call to index function.. so your `base_url()` too need to have `$id` at the end so that your function will get `$id` every time you make a call..

Comment: actually there is no need for pagination because u are specifying `$id` inside your `a.href` in the view so remove pagination..if it is not actually required... or explain your logic with more details..that what actually u r trying to do with this piece of code

Comment: Thanks to mr muhammad i got my result

Comment: if its really helps please mark it as answer so that any one else can get some help out of it